# Format date from UTC string

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, html

I have a time stamp in a JSON string that I want to break down. The format of the string is

```
"generatedAt": "2015-01-30T16:01:31.4019286+00:00",
```

This is consistent in terms of characters and numbers counts

I basically want to extract (in Javascript / JQuery)

```
generatedDate // the first part of the string up to the letter T
generatedTime // the xx:xx:xx after the letter T
```

so in this example `generatedDate = '2015-01-30'`, and `generatedTime = '16:01'`

There is a chance that this rendering of date time is a standard I just don't recognise and may be easily rendered with extracting parts of it.. but I don't recognise it so thats moot

Any assistance greatly appreciated

Comment: split and or regular expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value in the property can be converted to a date quite easily using the `Date` type:

```
var date = new Date("2015-01-30T16:01:31.4019286+00:00");
```

From there you can retrieve the parts of the date as required:

```
var dateString = date.getFullYear() + '-' + ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).substr(-2) + '-' + ("0" + date.getDate()).substr(-2);
var timeString = ("0" + date.getHours()).substr(-2) + ':' + ("0" + date.getMinutes()).substr(-2);

alert(dateString); // = "2015-01-30"
alert(timeString); // = "16:01"
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/0acw3zt1/)

You can simplify this massively if you use a date format library such as [DateJS](http://datejs.com) or [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com)

Comment: this is better than using a regex as the components will be in the users (browsers) timezone

Comment: Stunning! Many thanks for the very clear explanation and example